# Como recuperar o ID no JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, mysqli

O objetivo é popular um select de acordo com o select anterior.

Script

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#adms_grps_prod').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('#adms_tps_prod').hide();
                    //console.log('tipo ocultado');
                    $.get('../outros/tps_prods?search=', {adms_grps_prod: $(this).val(), ajax: 'false'}, function (j) {
                        var options = '<option value="">Escolha o Tipo</option>';
                        //console.log(options);
                        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                            //options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
                            //alert(j[i]);
                            console.log("Script: " + j);
                        }
                        $('#adms_tps_prod').html(options).show();
                        $('.carregando').hide();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Ocorreu um erro!');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Com o script acima, obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\site_delivery\adm\app\cpadms\outros\tps_prods.php:33:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'1'</font> <i>(length=1)</i>
</pre>ID: 1[{"id":"2","nome":"Cerveja Devassa 600ml"},{"id":"1","nome":"Cerveja Heineken 600ml"}]</html>
```

Como faço para pegar apenas o ID?

Answer (score 0):

Tentei isso para pegar o valor do id, selecionado no momento.

```
$('#adms_grps_prod option:selected').attr('id')
```

Comment: Já tinha feito desta maneira, porem apresentava "undefined".